# unit test case for cellRenderer in agGrid

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

I am trying to write unit test case for cellRenderer in agGrid but it's not covering line. below is the ts file code.

```
 protected loadDefinitions() {
 let format:any
 this.adjustmentsDataService
  .getColumnDefinitions()
  .then(definitions => {
    const columns: ColDef<any>[] = [];
    definitions.forEach(definition => {
      if (definition.fieldName.toLowerCase().includes('date')) {
        columns.push({
          headerName: definition.headerName,
          field: definition.fieldName,
          cellRenderer: (data:any) => {
          //  return moment(data.startDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm')
          return isMoment(data.startDate) ? 
          this.dateFormatPipe.transform(data.startDate, format) : data.startDate;
        }
        })
      }
```

And I have written below code for covering return statement from cellRenderer.

```
 it('should check cellRenderer of ColDef', () => {
 const data: any[] = [
   { starDate: '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z', }
 ];
 const columns: ColDef<any>[] = [
   {
    headerName: 'startDate',
    cellRenderer: data,
   }
 ]

const cellRenderer = columns.find(c => c.cellRenderer === data)?.cellRenderer as any;
expect(cellRenderer({ data: { startDate: '2022-01-01T00:00:00Z' } })).toEqual('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z');
expect(cellRenderer).toEqual('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z');
expect(cellRenderer.data).toBeTruthy();
})
```

But above code not covering single line or single word. and getting error like
**TypeError: cellRenderer is not a function.**
Below is the screenshot from coverage file.
[image]

Please help me for covering above line. I have tried lot but no luck.